# appengine hitting quota limit billing enabled set to unlimited

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, quota

My GAE app has billing enabled & it is set to unlimited.  Last night, it hit a quota limit on DB reads & stopped working.  I'm not the billing admin, but I can see that they charged $.97 & then credited the $.97 for over quota on DB reads.  I'm guessing we hit a "safety limit"?  Is there a way to verify this?  Is there something else that needs to be set up in the limits?  Quota was reset today & app is working fine.  Need to avoid hitting this again.
Thanks.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Hosting configuration/billing is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Quota page in the Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails). There is a link on that page to request additional quota if that is appropriate for your app.